# How to access Iframe inside another Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a web page and it contains few Iframes, It has iframes like this,

```
<html>
<iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" src="https://example.com">

    <iframe name="frame2" id="frame2" src="https://def.com/sample1.jsp"></iframe>
    <iframe name="frame3" id="frame3" src="https://def.com/sample2.jsp"></iframe>

</iframe>
</html>
```

Note that the **frame3** is opened when clicking a button on **frame2**. Now I need to call a javascript function which has been loaded with **frame2** from **frame3**.

It is clear that both frame 2 and 3 are from same origin so I did not expect a cross-origin frame issue. How do I get a reference to the frame2 and call the function? Lets say the function name is **doSomething()**

I was trying with `document.getElementById("frame2");` but it gives null. So I think there could be a different way of accessing iframes. Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using [contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow). Below is an example (note that this will give a same origin issue when run as a Snippet on SO):

```js
let iframe1 = document.getElementById("frame1").contentWindow;
let iframe2 = iframe1.document.getElementById("frame2");
let iframe3 = iframe1.document.getElementById("frame3");
```

```html
<iframe name="frame1" id="frame1">
  <iframe name="frame2" id="frame2"></iframe>
  <iframe name="frame3" id="frame3"></iframe>
</iframe>
```